# What's the difference between an object directly queried and an object querying one of its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add a class on the following object, everything is fine:

```
$('.select').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

But when I try to add a class to a child, I get an error:

```
$('.select').on('click', function() { 
    $(this).find('.list')[0].addClass('active'); 
});
```

From my research I've learned that certain objects have specific methods that can be called on them. So there must be a difference between

```
$(this)
```

and

```
$(this).find('.list')[0]
```

But I can't figure out what the difference would be, and I don't know how to find that out.

Comment: `$(this)` is constructs a JQuery object from `this`. `$(this).find('.list')[0]` is a `Node`. I hope this helps.

Comment: yes that did help thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `$(this)`is a jquery object, while `$(this).find('.list')[0]` is a DOM element, and doesn't have functions and methodsprovided by jQuery.

Because calling `$(this).find('.list')` will give you a `nodeList` and when you call `[0]` you will get the first node object from this list, and a node or a DOM element is different from a jquery object, as jQuery wraps a DOM elemnt with its utility methods and attributes.

So what you need to do is to convert this DOM element to a jQuery object so you can call jQuery methods on it:

```
$($(this).find('.list')[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).find('.list')[0]` returns a dom element from the jQuery object.

Elements don't have an `addClass()` method and you should be seeing an error in browser console telling you that

If you want the first one you can use `first()` or `eq()`

```
$(this).find('.list').first().addClass('active');
// OR
$(this).find('.list:first').addClass('active');
// OR
$(this).find('.list').eq(0).addClass('active');
```